# Work with JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

```
{"required_items":[
                   {
                    "filename":"abcd",
                    "no":"3"
                   },
                   {
                    "filename":"abc",
                    "no":"2"
                   }
                  ]}
```

I am not getting the code of the JSON format in Python  - I want to insert the filename and no through a loop.

---

```
list_of_other_ids={}
for i in xxxx:    
  entry={}
  entry['filename'] = "XXXX"
  entry['no'] =XX
  list_of_other_ids.append(entry)
```

I am doing like this... and it fails.

Comment: what do you have so far, what's the problem with what you have?

Comment: Please give an example of what you are trying to do or get a colleague who knows English better to help you write your question. I can't even make a good guess at what you are asking.

Comment: i want to store the values in json format in python....

Comment: JSON is just a string. Python can handle strings just fine.

Comment: yeah i know...but the problem is that filesname numbers are dictionary object and required items is list when i try to append in list it gives an error TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking about either, but http://docs.python.org/library/json.html will help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a valid format JSON in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198152/how-to-make-a-valid-format-json-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

```
# data.txt

{"required_items":[
                   {
                    "filename":"abcd",
                    "no":"3"
                   },
                   {
                    "filename":"abc",
                    "no":"2"
                   }
                  ]}
```

---

```
# parser.py

import json 

data = json.load(open('data.txt'))

for file in data:
    print file['filename']

# This will output:
#  abcd
#  abc
```

If you want to append new items:

```
data.append({ 'filename': 'foo',
            'nr': 1 })

json.dump(data, open('data.txt', 'w'))
```